# import images into an intelliJ Java project

Tags: image, intellij-idea

I am working on a Java project that requires the use of several images.  I'm on ubuntu linux  So I have an images folder inside my src directory.  So far so good but try as I might I can't seem to find a way to load or import image files into that images folder.  ( I want to be able to simply go something like loadImage("images/imageToLoad.png"); )

I have tried to just drag and drop.  I know that I could of course leave the program and use the linux filesystem to transfer the images but that's a pain and defeats the purpose of an IDE.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to do it in a file manager, outside of IntelliJ IDEA. To ensure that images are available in the application classpath check `Settings` | `Compiler` | `Resource Patterns`, `.png` extension needs to be listed there.

Comment: This is crazy as other IDEs (as Eclipse) can do an import from the file system. Why is that so that IntelliJ cannot do a simple import of a file?